# Python - How to delete some values in an array within a specific range?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have a vector array which is pt = [83. 0., 131. 0., 178. 0., 179. 0., 227. 0.]
So I want to compare these values with each other, and delete all the values that are in the range of +-5. For example in this array, I want to delete the value 179 because it's in the range of value 178 +-5. 
I tried this

```
for i in pt_list:
position = [i[0] for i in pt_list]
counter1 += 1 
if(counter1 > 1):
    if not position in range (prior_x0 - 5, prior_x0 +6):
        arr = np.array([[position, 0]])
        pt_list = np.append(later_pt_list, later_arr, axis = 0)
prior_x0 = position
a = pt_list[np.argsort(later_pt_list[:,0])]
```

print (a)

and result is still the same array :|

Comment: what results do you have? any code sample?

Comment: add code to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need? I have added a small bit to take care of the format of your entry data. I assume it is a text list with vectors. If not, you can change it accordingly.
I have a version with comprehension lists but it is quite ugly to read.
The output is 'list_float'.
I assumed you wanted to keep the first vector that are in the range of other ones, and remove the followings

```
# Make sure the format of your input is correct
list =  ['83. 0.', '131. 0.', '178. 0.', '179. 0.', '227. 0.']
list_float = []
for point in list:
    head, _, _ = point.partition(' ')
    list_float.append(float(head))

# This is the bit removing the extra part
for pos, point in enumerate(list_float):
    for elem in list_float[pos+1:]:
        if (elem < point+5.) and (elem > point-5.):
            list_float.remove(elem)

print(list_float)
```

Answer (score 0):

that's it you want?

```
pt_list = [83.0, 131.0, 178.0, 179.0, 227.0]
def removeNumbers(value,ran):
    return [x for x in pt_list if x not in (range(value + 1, value + (ran+1)) + range(value - ran, value))]
print removeNumbers(178,5)
```